# skype not in software centre ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, skype, downloads

I looked at answers for downloading skype and they all seem to be a bit dated.  can anyone tell me what exactly I should do to download the latest version of skype?
I have an ubuntu 14.04, have cleaned it, updated it, etc., and skype does not work so I purged it.  but skype is not in the software centre even though the canonical partners are all turned on.
from where exactly should I download skype?

Comment: there is no snap package in the software center.  i just downloaded linux deb from the skype website and it is now working.  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now you can download Skype latest version by clicking on `Get Skype for Linux Deb` from [here](https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/). I assume that downloaded files are saved in `~/Downloads` and file name is `skypeforlinux-64.deb`. Then run:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/skypeforlinux-64.deb
```

[Learn More about Debian Packaging](https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging)

Answer (score 0):

Install Skype on Ubuntu 14.04

1. Enable the Canonical partner repository:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
   ```
2. Update the local database with this command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Now install Skype:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install skype.
   ```

Source: [How to install Skype on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/install-skype-ubuntu-14-04/)

Comment: Thanks, I did all that and got : Package skype is not available, but is referred to by another package.  This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source.  However, the following packages replace it: skype-bin:i386

Comment: what do I do now?

Comment: Kulfy's answer is correct. Download from the skype website directly and install. His answer has the link to it and the instruction for installation as well. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that  Ubuntu 14 is no longer supported by skype as the latest version requires a later libsecret library than is supplied in ubuntu 14.

Comment: Good to know. Can you provide a reference for this or explain how you found out about it?